# Alfresco replace component advsearch

Tags: search, replace, alfresco-share

i successfully modified alfresco advseach. 
Now i have to replace the original. I really don't know how can i do this, until this moment i was working in share/target but i can't do that anymore. I need to somehow rewrite default url of advsearch. I need that Alfresco call my advsearch instead of default advsearch after clean installation or after command mvnclean.

I think that this should working:

```
<extension>         
  <modules>                
    <module>                      
      <id>ADVSearchExt</id>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>                        
      <components>                             
          <component>                                   
              <region-id>search</region-id>
              <source-id>advsearch</source-id>
              <scope>page</scope>                                    

              <url>/comp/advsearchext</url>                                         

          </component>                        
       </components>                  
     </module>            
    </modules>   
</extension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've created an alternative WebScript for the Component and you wish to swap it out. It's not possible to reconfigure an existing Component configuration as you are trying to do. What you actually need to do is to create one extension to remove the default component (see [this blog post](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/2011/07/27/how-to-hide-content-on-an-existing-alfresco-share-page/)) and then provide another component to render your WebScript (see [this blog post](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/2011/07/22/how-to-add-content-to-an-alfresco-share-page/)).

Comment: i've already use this and i can't render my own its just not working even if i rewrite to just simple page like this:
<div>dbsajdjasd</div>

Comment: That doesn't appear to be what you've described in your question... maybe you can update the question to show both the extensions to remove the original component and add your new one.

Comment: i add an answear whre i share both extensions i also described that unfortunately only one of them is working

Comment: it have to be in share part of the server, thanks for your advices

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: On subsequent reading of the question, I've realised that this original answer doesn't directly answer the question, however it does contain useful related information... I'll try and answer the actual question as well!*

Assuming you're using Alfresco 5.0 or 5.1 then the only way of accessing the advanced search page (via standard navigation) would be via the drop-down menu option in the header bar.

The header bar is an rendered by [Aikau](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau) and it is a relatively simple exercise to customize the header bar to navigate to an alternative page when you click on that "Advanced Search..." menu item.

This [blog post](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/2013/09/04/customizing-the-share-header-menu-part-1/) is the first in a 3-part series describing how you can customize the header bar.

The widget that you need to customize is the "[alfresco/header/SearchBox](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/SearchBox.html)" widget. Unfortunately, at the moment it doesn't off a simple configuration option for changing the page to navigate to. In this scenario you could raise an issue on the [Aikau Github page](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/issues) to make a request for this feature to be added. This would require that you wait for the feature to be included in a future release (releases are weekly) and then make use of that new configuration option.

The alternative would be to extend the default SearchBox widget and create a new extension module that swaps out the default SearchBox with your custom version. You would need to extend the `postCreate` function and remove `alfresco/menus/AlfMenuItem` that is created and replace it with one that has an appropriate `targetUrl`.

Unfortunately this is neither the most future proof or simplest solution, but is is possible. The most future proof solution (in terms of working with future upgrades to Alfresco) would be to make the feature request as clearly there are benefits to being able to reconfigure the advanced search page.